# ffmpeg lose frames when extracting them

Tags: ffmpeg

When I extract all frames from a video, FFmpeg lose one frame. I tried multiple options, like adding more parameters to the function, but none of them worked.

> ffmpeg  -i Multicam420-30a.mp4 -framerate 30 frame%08d.jpg
>
> ffmpeg version N-94077-g01d8c72b95 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
>     configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
>     libavutil      56. 29.100 / 56. 29.100
>     libavcodec     58. 53.100 / 58. 53.100
>     libavformat    58. 28.100 / 58. 28.100
>     libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
>     libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
>     libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
>     libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
>     libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
>   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023af91f9e80] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
>   [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000023af91f9e80] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
>   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Multicam420-30a.mp4':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : isom
>       minor_version   : 512
>       compatible_brands: mp41mp42
>       creation_time   : 2019-08-20T01:30:57.000000Z
>     Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11208 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11007 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2019-08-20T01:30:57.000000Z
>         encoder         : AVC Coding
>       Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2019-08-20T01:30:57.000000Z
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   [swscaler @ 0000023afb923740] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   Output #0, image2, to 'frame%08d.jpg':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : isom
>       minor_version   : 512
>       compatible_brands: mp41mp42
>       encoder         : Lavf58.28.100
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2019-08-20T01:30:57.000000Z
>         encoder         : Lavc58.53.100 mjpeg
>       Side data:
>         cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
>   frame=   29 fps= 17 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.96 bitrate=N/A speed=0.557x
>   video:3153kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

As you can see, the original video has 30 frames and last 1 second, and the output frames are 29 and less than a second.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 1 -i Multicam420-30a.mp4 -vsync 0 frame%08d.jpg`

Comment: Yes, it worked. It retrieved 30 frames as expected. What does -ignore_editlist do?